# prevent from credit by mysql transaction

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

i want to know how can i prevent from credit of user
for example i want to check the credit of user and then if credit is enough i minus total price from his credit

i searched and find [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292706/mysql-transaction-with-accounting-application) but its not very clear question 
i know about mysql transaction,atomic commands ,mutual exclusion,

but i cant find a simple question about php + mysql transaction 
all of the samples about 3 or 4 queries together and roll backing if exception occurs 
and not checking a statement with php inside of transaction section

thats my code
 is it correct?

```
$total_price = $count * $price;

mysqli_query("start transaction")

$credit = mysqli_query('select credit from users where uname="test"');
mysqli_query('update `credit`=`credit`-'.$total_price.' where uname="test"');


if($credit > $total_price)
 mysqli_query("commit")
else
 mysqli_query("rollback");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a single statement:

```
$result = mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET credit = credit - $total_price WHERE uname='test' AND credit >= $total_price");
$hadCredit = mysqli_affected_rows() > 0;
```